# Счет по условию из левого столбца

Tags: excel

у меня таблица:

```
16.09.2020  3,55
16.09.2020  -5,26
16.09.2020  4,18
15.09.2020  -3,07
15.09.2020  3,48
15.09.2020  2,56
14.09.2020  3,69
14.09.2020  -3,5
14.09.2020  -3,4
```

Мне нужно получить суммы за каждый их трех дней. Сначала я делаю третий столбец - в котором удаляю дубликаты из первого столбца, получаю

```
16.09.2020
15.09.2020
14.09.2020
```

Как получить в четвертом столбце соответствующие суммы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так (в каждую ячейку рядом с датой):

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$9; D1; $B$1:$B$9)
```